# GraalVM Quarkus Locale in native mode

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have an unexpected behavior with available locales when native build. I have only one locale available in native mode.

My application is very simple :

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationPathConfiguration extends Application {
}

@Path("/locales")
public class LocaleController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Locale[] get() {
        return Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    }

}
```

After checkout if I launch the application in dev mode :

```
mvn quarkus:dev
```

You can call the endpoint : http://localhost:8080/api/locales

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/locales
```

This endpoint return a lot of locales :

```
["","nn","ar_JO","bg","kea","nds","zu","am_ET","fr_DZ","ti_ET","bo_CN","hsb","qu_EC","ta_SG","lv","en_NU","zh_SG_#Hans","en_MS","en_GG","en_JM","vo","kkj","sr_ME","sv_SE","es_BO","dz_BT","mer","sah","en_ZM","fr_ML","br","ha_NG","ar_SA","fa_AF","dsb_DE","sk","os_GE","ml","en_MT","en_LR","ar_TD","en_GH","en_IL","sv","cs","el","tzm_MA","af","sw_UG","ses_ML","smn","tk_TM","sr_ME_#Cyrl","ar_EG","dsb","lkt_US","vai_LR_#Latn","ji_001","yo_NG","se_NO","khq","sw_CD","vo_001","en_PW","pl_PL","fil_PH","it_VA","sr_CS","ne_IN","es_PH","es_ES","es_CO","bg_BG","ji","ar_EH","bs_BA_#Latn","en_VC","nds_DE","nb_SJ","es_US","agq","hsb_DE","en_US_POSIX","en_150","ar_SD","en_KN","ha_NE","pt_MO","ebu","ro_RO","zh__#Hans","lb_LU","sr_ME_#Latn","es_GT","so_KE","dje_NE","bas_CM","fr_PM","ar_KM","fr_MG","no_NO_NY","es_CL","mn","agq_CM","kam_KE","teo","tr_TR","eu","fa_IR","en_MO","wo","shi__#Tfng","en_BZ","sq_AL","ar_MR","es_DO","ru","twq_NE","az","nmg_CM","fa","kl_GL","en_NR","nd","kk","az__#Cyrl","en_MP","en_GD","tk","hy","shi__#Latn","en_BW","en_AU","en_CY","kab_DZ","kde_TZ","ta_MY","ti_ER","nus_SS","en_RW","nd_ZW","sv_FI","ksb","luo","lb","ne","en_IE","zh_SG","ln_CD","en_KI","nnh_CM","om_ET","no","ja_JP","my","ka","ar_IL","mgh","or_IN","fr_MF","shi","kl","en_SZ","rwk_TZ","zh","es_PE","mgh_MZ","saq","az__#Latn","ta","en_GB","lag","zh_HK_#Hant","ar_SY","ksf_CM","bo","kk_KZ","es_PA","tt_RU","om_KE","ar_PS","en_AS","fr_VU","zh_TW","bez","kln","fr_MC","kw","pt_MZ","fr_NE","vai__#Latn","ksb_TZ","ksh","ur_IN","ln","en_JE","gsw_CH","ln_CF","en_CX","luy_KE","pt","en_AT","gl","kkj_CM","sr__#Cyrl","yue_CN_#Hans","es_GQ","kn_IN","ar_YE","to","en_SX","ga","qu","ru_KZ","en_TZ","et","en_PR","mua","ko_KP","in","ps","sn","nl_SR","rof","en_BS","km","zgh","fr_NC","be","gv","es","dua","gd_GB","jgo","nl_BQ","fr_CM","gsw","uz_UZ_#Cyrl","pa_IN_#Guru","en_KE","guz","mfe","asa_TZ","teo_UG","ja","fr_SN","or","brx","fr_MA","pt_LU","fr_BL","en_NL","mgo_CM","ln_CG","te","sl","ko_KR","el_CY","mr_IN","ha","es_MX","lrc_IR","gsw_FR","es_HN","hu_HU","ff_SN","sbp","sq_MK","sr_BA_#Cyrl","fi","uz","bs__#Cyrl","et_EE","sr__#Latn","en_SS","sw","bo_IN","fy_NL","ar_OM","tr_CY","nmg","rm","en_MG","fr_BI","uz_UZ_#Latn","bn","dua_CM","de_IT","lrc_IQ","vai__#Vaii","kn","fr_TN","sr_RS","de_CH","bn_BD","nnh","fr_PF","en_ZA","gu","pt_GQ","vun_TZ","jmc_TZ","en_TV","lo","fr_FR","en_PN","en_MH","fr_BJ","zh__#Hant","cu_RU","zh_HK_#Hans","nl_NL","sah_RU","en_GY","ps_AF","bs__#Latn","ky","mas","dyo_SN","os","bs_BA_#Cyrl","nl_CW","ar_DZ","sk_SK","pt_CH","fr_GQ","ff_CM","am","en_NG","fr_CI","ki_KE","en_PK","zh_CN","en_LC","rw","brx_IN","wo_SN","iw","gv_IM","mk_MK","en_TT","dav","sl_SI","fr_HT","te_IN","nl_SX","lrc","ses","ce","fr_CG","fr_BE","jgo_CM","mt_MT","es_VE","mg","mr","mer_KE","ko","nds_NL","en_BM","nb_NO","ak","seh","kde","dz","kea_CV","mgo","vi_VN","en_VU","en_US","to_TO","mfe_MU","seh_MZ","fr_BF","pa__#Guru","it_SM","fr_YT","gu_IN","ii_CN","pa_PK_#Arab","ast","fr_RE","fi_FI","yue__#Hans","ca_FR","sr_BA_#Latn","bn_IN","fr_GP","pa","zgh_MA","uk_UA","fr_DJ","rn","tg","rwk","hu","fr_CH","en_NF","twq","ha_GH","sr_XK_#Cyrl","bm","ar_SS","en_GU","nl_AW","de_BE","en_AI","en_CM","xog_UG","cs_CZ","tr","ca_ES","cgg","rm_CH","nyn_UG","ru_MD","ms_MY","ta_LK","ksf","en_TO","cy","en_PG","fr_CF","pt_TL","sq","fr","tg_TJ","en_ER","qu_PE","sr_BA","es_PY","de","es_EC","kok_IN","lg_UG","zu_ZA","fr_TG","sr_XK_#Latn","en_PH","ig_NG","fr_GN","prg_001","cgg_UG","zh_MO_#Hans","ksh_DE","lg","ru_RU","se_FI","ff","en_DM","en_CK","sd","ar_MA","ga_IE","en_BI","en_AG","fr_TD","en_WS","fr_LU","ebu_KE","bem_ZM","xog","ewo_CM","fr_CD","so","rn_BI","en_NA","ar_ER","kab","ms","nus","sn_ZW","prg","iw_IL","ug","es_EA","th_TH_TH_#u-nu-thai","hi","fr_SC","ca_IT","lag_TZ","en_SL","teo_KE","no_NO","ca_AD","zh_MO_#Hant","en_SH","vai","qu_BO","haw_US","vi","fr_CA","de_LU","sq_XK","dyo","en_KY","mt","it_CH","de_DE","si_LK","luo_KE","en_DK","yav","so_DJ","lt_LT","it_IT","eo","kam","ar_SO","en_ZW","ro","eo_001","ee","en_UM","nn_NO","fr_MU","pl","se_SE","en_TK","en_SI","mua_CM","ur","uz__#Arab","vai_LR_#Vaii","saq_KE","se","pt_GW","lo_LA","chr","ar_LB","af_ZA","ms_SG","ee_TG","ln_AO","be_BY","ff_GN","yue__#Hant","in_ID","es_BZ","ar_AE","hr_HR","luy","as","rof_TZ","it","pt_CV","ks_IN","uk","my_MM","ur_PK","mn_MN","da_DK","en_FM","es_PR","wae_CH","mzn","en_BE","ii","tt","fr_WF","ru_BY","mzn_IR","naq","fo_DK","en_SG","ee_GH","ar_BH","kln_KE","tzm","fur","om","hi_IN","en_CH","asa","yo_BJ","fo_FO","ast_ES","fr_KM","bez_TZ","fr_MQ","en_SD","es_AR","en_MY","ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese","es_SV","pt_BR","ml_IN","sbp_TZ","fil","en_FK","uz__#Cyrl","is_IS","yue_HK_#Hant","hy_AM","en_GM","en_DG","fo","ne_NP","hr","pt_ST","ak_GH","lt","uz_AF_#Arab","fur_IT","ta_IN","ccp","en_SE","fr_GF","lkt","zh_CN_#Hans","is","es_419","si","pt_AO","en_001","en","guz_KE","gsw_LI","ccp_BD","es_IC","ca","ru_KG","fr_MR","ar_TN","ks","zh_TW_#Hant","bm_ML","kw_GB","ug_CN","as_IN","es_BR","zh_HK","khq_ML","sw_KE","en_SB","th_TH","rw_RW","chr_US","shi_MA_#Tfng","ar_IQ","nyn","yue","jmc","en_MW","naq_NA","mk","en_IO","ar_QA","en_DE","pa__#Arab","en_CC","bs","ro_MD","en_FI","pt_PT","fy","az_AZ_#Cyrl","th","dav_KE","ckb_IQ","shi_MA_#Latn","es_CU","ar","en_SC","en_VI","haw","eu_ES","en_UG","en_NZ","dje","es_UY","bas","mas_KE","ru_UA","sg_CF","el_GR","yav_CM","uz__#Latn","sg","da_GL","en_FJ","de_LI","en_BB","km_KH","smn_FI","hr_BA","de_AT","ckb_IR","nl","lu_CD","ca_ES_VALENCIA","ar_001","so_SO","lv_LV","ckb","es_CR","fr_GA","ar_KW","sr","ar_LY","sr_RS_#Cyrl","bem","en_MU","da","wae","gl_ES","en_IM","az_AZ_#Latn","en_LS","ig","en_HK","en_GI","ce_RU","en_CA","gd","ka_GE","fr_SY","sw_TZ","fr_RW","so_ET","nl_BE","ar_DJ","mg_MG","cy_GB","en_VG","cu","os_RU","sr_RS_#Latn","en_TC","ky_KG","sv_AX","af_NA","vun","en_IN","lu","ki","yo","es_NI","nb","ff_MR","sd_PK","mas_TZ","ti","kok","ewo","ms_BN","ccp_IN","br_FR"]
```

If I do the same in native mode :

```
mvn clean package -Pnative && ./target/QuarkusLocale-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
```

I obtain only one locale :

```
["fr_US"]
```

How can I obtain all available locale ?

Moreover, because of this behavior I have another problem. As you can see if I tried to develop a service who want use locale. Locale is not use and I can't apply currency format. To demonstrate that, I develop CurrencyController.

```
@Path("/currency")
public class CurrencyController {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String get(String localeString) {
        String[] localeArray = localeString.split("-");
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeArray[0], localeArray[1]);

        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        numberFormat.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));
        return numberFormat.format(1337);
    }

}
```

You can call it with curl :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/currency -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "en-GB"
> US$1,337.00

curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/currency -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "en-US
> $1,337.00
```

If I do the same in native mode :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/currency -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "en-GB"
> US$1,337.00

curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/currency -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "en-US
> US$1,337.00
```

- Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM Version 19.3.1 CE
- Quarkus 1.4.1.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very [well-known issue on GraalVM](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/911). Currently, the only way to bypass it is to create Feature that will scan all locales at run time:

1. Add maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
            <artifactId>svm</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. Create Feature class

```
package org.example;

import com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.AutomaticFeature;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.ImageSingletons;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.Feature;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.impl.RuntimeClassInitializationSupport;

import java.util.Locale;

@AutomaticFeature
public class NativeLanguageFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public void beforeAnalysis(BeforeAnalysisAccess access) {
        ImageSingletons.lookup(RuntimeClassInitializationSupport.class).initializeAtBuildTime(SupportedLocales.class, "__");

        final Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        final SupportedLocales supportedLocales = new SupportedLocales();
        supportedLocales.locales = availableLocales;
        ImageSingletons.add(SupportedLocales.class, supportedLocales);
    }

    public static class SupportedLocales {
        public Locale[] locales;
    }
}
```

3. In a place where you want to access locales, check if SupportedLocales present in `ImageSingletons`

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Locale[] get() {
        if(ImageSingletons.contains(NativeLanguageFeature.SupportedLocales.class)){
            final NativeLanguageFeature.SupportedLocales lookup = ImageSingletons.lookup(NativeLanguageFeature.SupportedLocales.class);
            return lookup.locales;
        }
        return Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    }
```

You probably will need to do same thing with money as well.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This happens to keep the native executable small as possible, so only the default locale is added to the bundle. The GraalVM allows you to add more custom locales at build time with `-H:IncludeLocales=fr,en,...`.

More information in https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/native-image/Resources/#locales