# Quarkus: IllegalArgumentException during build

Tags: quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that runs without any problems with `./gradlew quarkusDev`.

However if I try to build the application, and it makes no difference if I use `quarkusBuild`, `buildNative` or `build`, the `ClassVisitor` throws a lot of `IllegalArgumentException`s for these classes / methods (for brevity omitting similar stack traces after first exception):

```
Execution failed for task ':quarkusBuild'.
> io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildSteps#generateConfigSources threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.gizmo.GizmoClassVisitor.<init>(GizmoClassVisitor.java:22)
    at io.quarkus.gizmo.ClassCreator.writeTo(ClassCreator.java:150)
    at io.quarkus.gizmo.ClassCreator.close(ClassCreator.java:203)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildSteps.generateConfigSources(ConfigBuildSteps.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:936)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.BootstrapConfigSetupBuildStep#setupBootstrapConfig threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.logging.LoggingResourceProcessor#registerMetrics threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.netty.deployment.NettyProcessor#eagerlyInitClass threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.logging.LoggingResourceProcessor#setupLoggingStaticInit threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.vertx.http.deployment.HttpSecurityProcessor#initBasicAuth threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.vertx.http.deployment.HttpSecurityProcessor#initMtlsClientAuth threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)

    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.vertx.core.deployment.VertxCoreProcessor#ioThreadDetector threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    // ... (Stacktrace omitted for brevity)
```

Does anyone know what is causing these exceptions and how to solve this?

I am using Quarkus 1.9.2.Final, Kotlin 1.4.10, Gradle 6.5 and JDK 11.

Below are my application.properties and my build.gradle:

```
quarkus.http.port=6543

quarkus.native.enable-https-url-handler=true
quarkus.native.enable-all-security-services=true
```

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.4.10"
    id 'io.quarkus'
}


def javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

java {
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = javaVersion
    kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = javaVersion
}


dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:$quarkusVersion")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}


quarkus {
    setOutputDirectory("$projectDir/build/classes/kotlin/main")
}

quarkusDev {
    setSourceDir("$projectDir/src/main/kotlin")
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
    annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
    annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567216/graalvm-quarkus-locale-in-native-mode

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?